# Convergence in the uniform norm topology, convergence wrt the uniform norm and uniform convergence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Examples)

> Given a topological space $X$, we can equip the space of bounded real
>   or complex-valued functions over $X$ with the uniform norm topology.
>   Then uniform convergence simply means convergence in the uniform norm
>   topology.

I was wondering

1. Is convergence in the uniform norm topology same as convergence wrt the
   uniform norm?
2. what relations are between convergence wrt the uniform norm,  and
   uniform convergence? Contrary to what Wiki says, I think that
   convergence wrt the uniform norm implies uniform convergence, but
   not vice versa. This is because the  uniform norm is defined to be
   taking sup over the domain, stronger than the case of uniform
   convergence where "for each distance in codomain, there exists a
   distance in domain and consider all pair of domain points apart within
   this distance". Am I wrong?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are wrong: they are exactly the same.  If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $X$, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that whenever $n > N$, $|f_n(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x\in X$.  But that says $\sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x) - g(x)| \le \epsilon$.  The difference between $\le$ and $<$ is not significant: if you want $\sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon$, just take an $N$ that implies $|f_n(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon/2$.

Answer (score 1):

The topology is give by the supremum norm $\| f\|_\infty=sup\{|f(x)|: x\in X\}   $, and sequence converges $ f_n$ converges to $f$ iff $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.